# How do I achieve this very bright and clear portrait look?

Tags: portrait, technique, reverse-engineering

Extremely bright eyes and contrast. Not sure if this is photoshopped or achieved through lighting and lenses.

I have even seen this sort of effect in live video.. any ideas on how to do this look?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hi-key effect of this image is achieved using a series of lights that makes the subject like being immersed in light.
In this particular case there are for sure two frontal lights (probably within and angle of 30/45 degrees on the median of the head). Behind the subject there were probably two others light sources used to profile the chin of the woman.
The high contrast can be achieved using some sharpening filter in photoshop or, more easily, shooting between two or more panels covering the direct lights coming from the light sources.
[image: A possible example of light diagram]

Comment: Excellent answer! The chin/jaw highlights might also have been created by reflectors bouncing some light from the two front lights. Silver reflectors in particular can give the light a hard look.

Answer (score 3):

That's called "high key" lighting. There are many [tutorials](http://www.studioonashoestring.com/22/high-key-portrait-lighting-tutorial-2/) on the net that explain how it's done. Mostly, it comes down to putting *enough* light on your subject and *more* light on the background, so that the subject is well lit and the background becomes pure white.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the *[high key](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10232/what-does-it-mean-for-a-photograph-to-be-high-key)* lighting it appears some *[selective sharpening](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9741/how-do-you-get-the-eyes-extremely-sharp-in-the-photo/9752#9752)* around the eyes has been done as well. And I wouldn't be surprised if the editor also used some *[frequency separation](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/37985/15871)* to even out the skin tones a little.